# Extracting all value from a data set based for every categorical numerical value in R

Tags: r, dataset, extract

I have a data set with an arbitrary number of row and two columns:a and b. I would like to find the number of a values for a specific value of b. If given the data set below I would want a1 = 2, a2 = 1 for a set value of b1.

```
  a   b
  1   1
  1   1
  2   1
  2   2
  3   2
  3   2
```

Code that I've tried and works:

```
 data[a == 1 & b == 1, list(b = length(b))]
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
data[a == c(1,2) & b == 1, list(b = length(b))]
```

How can I get all values of a for a set b value?

Expected data output:

```
    b1 
a1  2
a2  1
a3  0
etc.
```

Code that works thanks to akrun:

```
library(data.table)
table(as.integer(data$a),data$b=='b1')[,2]
```

Make sure your `[,2]` matches your 'b' column.
Also, `as.integer()` ranks the values in order.

Comment: Try `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, .N,.(a,b)]`  It is confusing, can you show the expected output?

Comment: @akrun probably `setDT(df)[b == 1, .N, by = a]` or `setDT(df)[b == 1, table(a)]`

Comment: Btw, is this a `data.table` question?

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is not mentioned in the post and not tagged.

Comment: I added expected data output, but I will try some of the things you suggested. Note that called it "a1" so that it is less confusing. In actuality it would just the values of a in a list = "1","2","3", etc.

Comment: @akrun "Code that I've tried and works:" only works with data.table, though.

Comment: @Frank Yes, but it was not explicitly mentioned

Comment: What does `etc.` mean? What comes after etc.? Can you make your desired output complete?

Comment: This should work: `DT[, sum(b==1), by=a]`

Comment: @BC No need to edit the answer into the question. It's expected that future readers of this page will scroll down to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
 table(within(data, b<-b==1))[,'TRUE', drop=FALSE]
```

EDIT: Included @Frank's suggestion.

Comment: This worked great, thank you akrun. And thank you for your huge contribution to stackoverflow in general.